# get first and last element in ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have small code where i have to add condition to get proper output.

if the element inside the mimeList is Last then go to **else** part.
or to the **if**.

there is always 1 element in this ArrayList.

(if it has only one element then it means it is  last element.)

```
for (int i = 0; i < mimeList.size(); i++) {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    if () {
        queryString = sb.append(queryString).append(key)
        .append("=").append(mimeList.get(i)).append(" or ").toString();
    }else{
        queryString = sb.append(queryString).append(key)
        .append("=").append(mimeList.get(i)).toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!(i == 0 || i == mimeList.size()))`?

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly you're asking...

Comment: @auser if is blank, must be where he wants code?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist `i` cannot be equal to `mimeList.size()`

Comment: Pasting your homework? Move StringBuffer out of the loop. Get rid of that ugly redundancy. Check that there's a space between keys. What about the "or" between first and second list item? Good luck.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer when you can use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simpler way to do with without lots of checks is to use seperator which is empty to start with.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sep = "";
for (String s : mimeList) {
    sb.append(sep + key + "=" + s);
    sep = " or ";
}
```

Comment: :I have edited my question. Plz chk and help.
if the element inside the mimeList is Last then go to else part. or to the if.

Comment: All you need is " or " between the key=value pairs. This is the simplest way to do that. You don't need an `if` and you don't need to repeat the code.

Answer (score 11):

Regarding the heading of your question:

> get first and last element in ArrayList in Java

It should be pretty simple:

```
mimeList.get(0); // To get first
mimeList.get(mimeList.size()-1); //to get last
```

And regarding your `if` condition :

```
if(!(i==0 || i==mimeList.size()-1))
```

As you phrased it like:

> if the element in mimeList is first or last it will go in else
>   condition other wise in if condition

I used `!` in if condition.
 Otherwise below is pretty cool:

```
if((i>0) && (i!=mimeList.size()-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like so should work: `if ((i > 0) && (i < mimeList.size() - 1))`. Since in Java collections as 0 based, the first element will be at location `0` and the last will be at `Collection.Size - 1`, since accessing the `Collection.Size`th location will cause an out of bounds exception.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather from your question, you want something like the following:

```
ArrayList<Foo> foos = fooGenerator.generateFoos();

for(int i = 0; i < foos.size(); i++) {
    if(i != (foos.size() - 1)) {
        System.out.println("Front elements of ArrayList");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Last element of ArrayList!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<int> foos = ArrayList<int>();
```

for the first is

```
foos.get(0);
```

for the last is

```
foos.get(foo.size - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the `i` is `Integer` inside the `ArrayList.`

```
if ((i > 0) && (i < mimeList.size() - 1))
```

Comment: Technically `i` is an `int` (a primitive), not an `Integer` (an object).

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra  I have edited my question. Plz chk and help.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
if(i == 0 || i == mimeList.size() - 1)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah, was a bit to quick there. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have the answer already in your code:

You loop from the *first* to the *last* element in your array.

first: having index 0,
last: having index (size - 1)

This results in the following condition:

```
if ((i > 0) && (i < mimeList.size() - 1))
```